# Material UI in page navigation

Tags: reactjs, navigation, material-ui

Can anyone help me create this in-page navigation that changes as you scroll through the page? I can’t find any documentation on it. It is on the right side of the photo.

[image: material-ui image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the github file: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/modules/components/AppTableOfContents.js.

They detect the scroll with `window.addEventListener('scroll')` and map the scroll position to the node location of the chapter titles.